# Express.js- Calling three Dependent MongoDB queries sequentially for each loop

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have to insert multiple different JSON objects in MongoDB and then check whether the some of the data already exist in the database and run another query based on whether the data exists or not for each JSON Object. How can I do in expressjs? I am using mongojs package for working with MongoDB. The code I typed is below:

```
app.post('/addcard/:id', function(req, res) {
console.log("Received Add Card Request");
var date = new Date();
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDate();
var yrval = req.body.yrval;
var monval = req.body.monval;
var dateval = req.body.dateval;

for (var i=0;i<req.body.phone.length;i++){
  //console.log(i);
  var card = new Card({

    cardType                    : req.body.cardtype,
    cardTitle                   : req.body.cardtitle,
    allowMultipleStore          : false,
    phoneNumber                 : req.body.phone[i],
    messageUser                 : req.body.message,
    expiryDate                  : new Date(year+yrval,month+monval,day+dateval),
    creditPoints                : req.body.creditpoints,
    punchCount                  : req.body.punch,
    messageReachPunchLimit      : req.body.limitmessage,
    merchantUsersId             : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.merchantuserid),
    merchantId                  : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
  });
console.log(card);
  db.carddata.insert(card, function (err,docInserted){

   // console.log(card);
   console.log(i);
    if (err) throw err;

    db.userdata.find({phoneNumber:req.body.phone},function (err,docs){
      console.log("hiss");
      if (err) throw err;

      if (docs.length!=0){
        var carduser = new CardUsersAssignment({

  cardId                            : docInserted._id,
  userId                            : docs[0]._id,
  remainingCreditPoints             : req.body.creditpoints,
  remainingPunchCount               : req.body.punch
  });
        db.carduser.insert(carduser,function (err){

      console.log(" Card Details saved successfully_existing");
        //console.log(i);



        })

      }//If (docs.length!=0)
      else{

  console.log(" Card Details saved successfully");

}


    })//Finding by PhoneNumber
    console.log(i+1);


})//Insert Function
console.log("hi");

} // End of For Loop
res.json({
  success:true,
  message:"Hello. You did it!"
});

});
```

This code is written as if I were writing for sequential execution. I know that NodeJS is asynchronous. I tried async.waterfall but it is giving error with the mongodb query function. Any help would be great. I am a NodeJS noob. Links to article which discuss similar scenarios would also be great.

Comment: This should be fixed with the waterfall method. Can you put your async.waterfall code here and the error you are getting when you run it?

Comment: I have followed the example given in the following page:
https://codeforgeek.com/2016/04/asynchronous-programming-in-node-js/

except in before function I added db.carddata.insert() so on as I did in the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using async library.
There is two way to do it.

1. Use async each to iterate your data and inside each check data is first check data is already exist or not, based on find result you can return or insert the doc.
2. It is the same as 1st, the only different is you just can to use waterfall for find and insert.

First Approach:

```
async.each(req.body.phone, function(data, callback) {
  // Create card Info
  db.carddata.insert(card, function (err,docInserted){
    if (err) {throw err;}
    db.userdata.find({phoneNumber:req.body.phone},function (err,docs){
      if (err) {throw err;
      } else if ( docs.length ){
         // create carduser data
         db.carduser.insert(carduser,function (err){
           if (err) {throw err;}   
           callback();           
         }
      } else {
         console.log(" Card Details saved successfully");
         callback();
      }

  }
}, function(err) {
  // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
  if( err ) {
    // One of the iterations produced an error.
    // All processing will now stop.
    console.log('A file failed to process');
  } else {
    console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
  }
});
```

Second Approach:

```
async.each(req.body.phone, function(data, callback) {
   //create card data
   let data = {}
   data.phone = req.body.phone;
   data.docInserted = data.docInserted;
   data.cardata = cardData;
   async.waterfall([
     insertCard,
     updateDataFind,
     cardDataInsert,
     async.apply('insertCard', data)
   ], function (err, result) {
    if(err){
      if(err.success){
        callback();
      }
      throw err;
    }
    callback();
   });
}, function(err) {
  // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
  if( err ) {
    // One of the iterations produced an error.
    // All processing will now stop.
    console.log('A file failed to process');
  } else {
    console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
  }
});
function insertCard(data, callback){
  db.carddata.insert(card, function (err,data.docInserted){
    if(err){throw err;}
    callback(null, data);
  }
}
function updateDataFind(data, callback){
  db.userdata.find({phoneNumber:data.phone},function (err,docs){
     if (err) {throw err;}
     else if (docs.length!=0){ callback(null, data); }
     else { callback({success:true}) }
  }
}
function cardDataInsert(data, callback){
   // create card user or pass from data.
   db.carduser.insert(carduser,function (err){
     if (err) {throw err;}
     callback(null, data);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: But the Solution is not working. Anyway, thanks once again for trying.